# GCC vs VS anonymous types as template arguments

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

This code compiles with VS (/za) but doesn't compile with GCC. Who is right and who is wrong? Or both are wrong/right?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

struct NullType
{
    //NullType(){}
template<class T>
    NullType(T value){}
enum {value};
};

template<class T>
struct IntType
{
    typedef T type;

};

template<int value_>
struct Low
{
    typedef int type;
    enum {value = value_};
};

template< class T>
struct Low_impl
{
protected:
T value_;
Low_impl():value_(T()){/*e.b.*/}
Low_impl(T value):value_(value){/*e.b.*/}
};

template<class T>
struct isNullType
{
    enum {value = false};
};

template<>
struct isNullType<NullType>
{
    enum {value = true};
};

template<class T>
struct TypeTraits
{
    typedef T type;
};



/*template<>
struct TypeTraits<int>
{
    typedef int type;
};*/

template<class Int_>
struct Int_Type_Tag
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<Int_>::type,"Non Integral Type Is ILLEGAL As a Parameter to this class ");
    typedef Int_ type;
};

template<class T>
struct TypeTraits<Int_Type_Tag<T>>
{
    typedef typename Int_Type_Tag<T>::type type;
};

template<class Int_Type,class L = NullType>
struct Int : private std::conditional<isNullType<L>::value,
                                      NullType,
                                      Low_impl<typename TypeTraits<Int_Type>::type>>::type
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<isNullType<L>::value,
                                      NullType,
                                      Low_impl<typename TypeTraits<Int_Type>::type>>::type BaseType;
Int():BaseType(L::value){}
};

int main()
{
    Int<int> a;
    cout << sizeof(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Error from GCC 4.5.1
error: no matching function for call to 'NullType::NullType(NullType::&)'|

Comment: I voted to close as not a real question. How the hell are any of us supposed to know when you don't post what the code is supposed to *do* or how it's supposed to do it, or the compiler error from GCC?

Comment: What error do you get in GCC? And where?

Comment: And I'm removing `boost` tag. There is no `boost` anything in the question.

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using? It gets compiled at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/nI5bg)

Comment: added error msg from GCC

Comment: Missing `template<class T>` before `struct NullType`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate `NullType::NullType(T)` with the type of an anonymous enum `NullType::value`.

This was allowed by [N2657](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2657.htm), which is implemented in [gcc 4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/cxx0x_status.html).

Comment: Good answer - I've changed the title to make it more useful

Comment: but is "this" as you're saying allowed by newest draft, namely 3242? And why does it compile on VS but not on GCC?

Comment: @There – In C++ 1998 this restriction was in [temp.arg.type]: "A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type ... shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter." This clause was modified somewhere along the way to refer to the definition of external linkage, but N2657 completely removed it, and it is absent in the latest draft. I guess VS implemented this sooner, or possibly failed to implement the restriction when it was still in the standard. I'm not sure why you get an error in gcc 4.5.1; gcc 4.5.3 compiles it fine.